# How to create a numbered ordered text in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I need to create a instruction screen for cocos2d game. Please kindly let me know how to create the Numbered ordered list instructions in cocos2d game. You can see the same of how the text should be

[image]

Comment: Also if the instruction is big it need to be scrollable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, windowSize.height/2,windowSize.width/2)];
 textView.text = @"your text here";
 [textView setEditable:NO]; 
 [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view]addSubview:textView];
```

try this